# Oracle Apex Tabular forms apex_application.g_f array not populating

Tags: oracle-apex, tabular-form

I am in the process of developing a Tabular form based on a simple query from a table. I have added the add row functionality in the form.

Now, here is what I want to do. Let's say my query is based on emp table, and when the user enters the empid I should fetch the empname and display it in the textfield next to empid. I have tried using `apex_application.g_f` arrays but this is always returning count as 0. I have tried arrays `g_f01` to `g_f10` just to see if the array is populated somwhere but the count `apex_application.g_f01.count` to `apex_application.g_f10.count` is always coming as 0.

However I tried using the below javascript code and its showing the values.

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.wwv_flow.f04.length; i++)
{
    var vTemp=$(document.wwv_flow.f04[i]).val();
    alert(vTemp);
}
```

Just to add a point, I have the row selector as well. I use a dynamic action to get the count.

Can someone help me to identify why the `apex_application.g_f` array is not populated?

Answer (score 2):

The `apex_application.g_f` arrays are only populated when the page is submitted, i.e. they can be accessed from processes that run on page submit.  But they do not persist when the page is reloaded.  Javascript is the right way to access these from the page itself.